# SQLIte SUM datetimes

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a database with rows, with time values. I want a SUM of that time values (generaly, the format are %H:%M).

I used SUM value like that:

```
SELECT SUM(n_hores) FROM table;
```

But only I get 0.0.

How I can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Time values in `hh:mm` format are strings, and strings cannot be summed meaningfully.

You should convert these time values into a number (`strftime(%s)` returns the number of seconds since 1970-01-01, so you have to subtract the offset from the start of the day to get the number of seconds corresponding to your time value):

```sql
SELECT sum(strftime('%s', MyTime) - strftime('%s', '00:00')) FROM MyTable
```

You can also convert this number of seconds back into a time string (`time()` returns it in `hh:mm:ss` format):

```sql
SELECT time(sum(strftime('%s', MyTime) - strftime('%s', '00:00'))) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: When I do that select strftime('%s', n_hores) from table, I get null values :S n_hores is a DATETIME column

Comment: Ok, the value must be 00:15 :p

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off subtracting the two dates by getting the "number of milliseconds since the last epoch aka (modern epoch)." There should be a function, in SQLite, that returns the number of milliseconds since the last epoch. Once you've found this, the solution should be a simple subtraction and conversion to seconds, minutes and/or hours.